# Ошибка в алгоритме

Tags: c++, олимпиада, теория-чисел

Закодил алгоритм проверки числа на то, является ли оно степенным, работает хорошо, но проверка не засчитывает 1 тест. В первой строке количество чисел которые нужно проверить, от 1 до 10 включительно, потом сами числа от 1 до 10 в 9 степени включительно. Основной принцип проверки - раскладывание числа на простые множители, и если нет ни одного простого множителя, который повторяется, то число не степенное.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
bool f(int b);

int main() {
    int n, b;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> b;
        if (step(b)) cout << "YES" << endl;
        else cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
}

bool f(int b)
{
    long double T=2;
    for (double i = 2; T>1.9; i++)
    {
    T = floor((pow(b, 1.0 / i)*1000000))/1000000;
    if ((double)T == (int)T) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Проверял много случаев, в том числе и 1 и 1000000000 и простые числа, работает как нужно

Comment: я думаю, что проблема в том, что ваш код распознает `1` как степенное число.

Comment: Делал условие, при вводе 1 оно распознаёт как не степенное, но всёравно не проходит тест

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста. Степенные числа - это какие числа? Просто в таких задачах это может быть число например `8 = 2 * 2 * 2`, а так же я видел что степенное число это `31 = 2^2 + 3^3`

Comment: Дайте URL проверяющей системы, посмотреть, как *точно* сформулирована задача...

Answer (score 5):

Если степенные числа это те, которые можно получить из некоторого числа умножением на себя хотя бы один раз.

Вот достаточно быстрый алгоритм основанный на свойствах логарифма:

```
double log2Values(int x, int y) {
    return log(x) / log(y);
}

bool f(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i) {
        if (fabs(log2Values(n, i) - round(log2Values(n, i))) < 1e-7)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

А так у вас если ввести число `72`, то выведется `"YES"`, что не правильно.

Код выше хоть и простой, но очень долгий и не точный. На числах уже больше 1 миллиона может выдавать неправильные значения.

Пример быстрого и эффективного кода предоставил @StanislavVolodarskiy.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy все тесты пройдены. И да все хватит. 

Формула перехода к новому основанию: `loga(b) = log(b)/log(a)`

Comment: ошибку понял, нужно проверять, если степени простых множителей числа отличаются, то число не степенное

Comment: @Zeor6 у вас по времени не проходит мой код???

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy проверил с `ulong` и все нормально.

Comment: @Zeor6, вы неправильно поняли. 144 = 2^4 * 3^2 - степенное. Нужно считать НОД показателей степеней.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy странно он выкладывал url на проверяющую систему в комментариях, где степенное число это те, которые можно получить из некоторого числа умножением на себя хотя бы один раз.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy сделал, через нсд, если нсд 1, то сразу выводить нет. Но этот алгоритм тоже с ошибкой, не проходит тест, причём тот же, что не проходил с тем кодом

Comment: @Zeor6 если у вас другая проверяющая система(не так что вы скидывали в первый раз), то дополните пожалуйста вопрос ссылкой на эту систему.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков та же

Comment: @Zeor6 ну а чем вам не нравится мой код? Или вы хотите именно свою идею добить?

Comment: `144 = 12^2`. Так это степенное или нет?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в той системе, что автор вопроса скидывал, да!

Comment: Этот код прошел на e-olymp на ура...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вы правы. Тут проблема с `double` идет проверка `3.0...04 < 3`. Изменил код

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я понимаю, к чему вы все клоните. Так вот поработайте над своей еще функцией. Проверьте число `39304`

Comment: `39304 = 34^3`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy к чему добавлять 0.5? Не очень понял.

Comment: `round(x) == (int)(x + 0.5)`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а господи это. Понял.

Comment: Ошибка: `f(1413722) -> true`. Причина: `log(1413722)/log(1189) - 2 = 9.989635563201205e-08 < 1e-7`, но `1189^2 = 1413721`. :(

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да все вы победили. Мой код имеет проблему с точность да еще и промежуток [500000; 1000000] работает за 84к+ миллисекунд. Ваш код и точнее и на этом же промежутке работает всего за 500 миллисекунд.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy подправил ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117314/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and--).

Answer (score 4):

**Предупреждение**: хотя этот способ работает, есть способ [лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219496/416121).

Разлагаем на простые множители и подсчитываем НОД их степеней в разложении.

Если НОД не единица, то он есть степень в которую можно возвести (неизвестное нам) число и получить `n`.

Несколько примеров:

```
  3 = 3^1       -> НОД(1)    = 1 -> обычное
  4 = 2^2       -> НОД(2)    = 2 -> степенное
  6 = 2^1 * 3^1 -> НОД(1, 1) = 1 -> обычное
 36 = 2^2 * 3^2 -> НОД(2, 2) = 2 -> степенное
 72 = 2^3 * 3^2 -> НОД(3, 2) = 1 -> обычное
144 = 2^4 * 3^2 -> НОД(4, 2) = 2 -> степенное
```

Разложение сделано перебором делителей `i` с двойки до тех пор пока `i^2 <= n`. Если делитель найден (`n % i == 0`), то делим `n` на него пока делится. Процесс продолжается дальше. Получается цикл в котором возможный делитель `i` растёт, а делимое `n` убывает. Цикл не самый оптимальный: например проверять чётные делители кроме двух не имеет смысла.

Получив разложение (например `2^4 * 3^2`) считаем НОД показателей степеней (`НОД(4, 2) = 2` в нашем примере). Сами множители нас не интересуют.

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 powerful_numbers.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (b > 0) {
        int t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}

bool powerful(int n) {
    int g = 0;
    int j = 2;
    while (n > 1) {
        int divisor = n;
        for (; j * j <= n; ++j) {
            if (n % j == 0) {
                divisor = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        int power = 0;
        while (n % divisor == 0) {
            n /= divisor;
            ++power;
        }

        g = gcd(g, power);
        if (g == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


void check(int n) {
    std::cout << n << ' ' << powerful(n) << '\n';
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        check(i);
    }
    check(36);
    check(72);
    check(144);
}
```

Результат:

```
0 1
1 1
2 0
3 0
4 1
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 1
9 1
36 1
72 0
144 1
```

Comment: `0` и `1` это степенные числа?

Comment: Да. `0 = 0^2`, `1 = 1^2`.

Comment: Дополните свой ответ объяснением, как работает ваш код. Можно с комментариями. Это чтобы на ваш ответ обращали внимание сразу.

Comment: Не проходит с нод, написал новый код с перебором n-ых корней, но он тоже не проходит, залил код здесь, проходит только на 80%

Comment: @Zeor6, [решение засчитано](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/8072029).

Answer (score 1):

### Ошибка

Ваш способ не работает из-за ошибок округления и неправильного применения конструкции `(int)`. И `long double` не лучше чем `double` в этой ситуации.

Пусть `n = 125`.

Выражение `pow(125, 1.0/3.0)` вычисляется в `4.999999999999999`. Так может быть: для функции возведения в степень нет гарантий точного результата, даже если этот результат представим в виде `double` без искажений. :(

Выражение `floor(4.999999999999999 * 1000000) / 1000000` вычисляется в `4.999999`. Здесь сознательно занижается точность, но это не беда.

Выражение `(int)4.999999` вычисляется в `4`. Ошибка тут. Малая до сих пор ошибка округления стала катастрофой.

Округление можно поправить с `(int)` на `round` и этот случай вычислится правильно. Зато перестанут правильно вычислятся такие вещи:

```
2**29 = 536870912
pow(536870911, 1.0/29.0) = 1.9999999998715416
pow(536870912, 1.0/29.0) = 2.0
pow(536870913, 1.0/29.0) = 2.000000000128458
```

### Исправление

Пусть `p` - степень которую мы проверяем. Вычислим корень степени `p` и расстояние от корня до ближайшего целого:

```
double root = std::pow(n, 1. / p);
double error = std::abs(root - std::round(root));
```

Даже если у числа есть точный корень степени `p` ошибка может не быть равной нулю. Если у корня нет точного корня степени `p` можно надеятся что ошибка будет достаточно велика. Проверить можно на всех числах `n`. Несколько часов на миллиард тестов и результат готов. Если число степенное, то ошибка не больше 3.41061e-13. Если число не степенное, то ошибки для всех степеней не меньше 1.28458e-10. Ура! Вот работающий вариант:

```
bool powerful(int n) {
    int powers[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
    for (int p : powers) {
        double root = std::pow(n, 1. / p);
        double error = std::abs(root - std::round(root));
        if (error < 1e-11) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Эта функция быстрее всех: десять раз извлекаем корень и проверяем расстояние до целого. Всё. Единственное что трудно объяснить, так это почему она работает и что такое `1e-11`.

### Другое решение

Чтобы найти ошибки в предыдущем разделе нужно знать какие числа степенные а какие нет. Здесь приводится другой метод выяснения степенности числа.

Из целого числа `0 <= n <= 10^9` извлечём корни простой степени от 2 до 29. Полученные корни округлим и возведём обратно в соответствующие степени. **Возводить нужно точно**. Результаты сравним с `n`. Если есть совпадение - `n` степенное число.

Простых степеней достаточно, так если `n` - степенное число по составной степени, то `n` - степенное и по любому делителю степени: `n = r^(ab) = (r^a)^b`.

```
bool powerful(int n) {
    int powers[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
    for (int p : powers) {
        double root = std::round(std::pow(n, 1. / p));
        if (pow(root, p) == n) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Функция возведения в степень самая простая, но точная. `double` выбран так как для целых возможно переполнение, которое не хочется контролировать *(позже выяснилось что переполнения именно в этой задаче не бывает никогда)*. Вещественные числа в нужном нам диапазоне перемножаются точно. Иначе говоря, что `double`, что `long long` будут вести себя одинаково в нашей задаче:

```
double pow(double k, int p) {
    double r = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
        r *= k;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Этот способ также проходит проверку на [e-olymp](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/2328). Он проще [разложения на простые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219300/416121), работает быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Просто и незатейливо, и даже не слишком оптимально - но с гарантией и проходимостью :) e-olymp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int qpow(int x, unsigned int e)
{
    int res = 1;
    for(;e;e>>=1)
    {
        if (e&1) res *= x;
        x *= x;
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        double x = log(n);
        for (int j = 2; j*j <= n; ++j)
        {
            int p = int(x/log(j)+0.5);
            if (qpow(j,p) == n) { n = 0; break; }
        }
        cout << (n ? "NO" : "YES") << endl;
    }
}
```

Забавно, что решение побыстрее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int qpow(int x, unsigned int e)
{
    int res = 1;
    for(;e;e>>=1)
    {
        if (e&1) res *= x;
        x *= x;
    }
    return res;
}

unsigned int pp[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 };

bool isPow(int n)
{
    double x = log(n);
    for(auto p: pp)
    {
        int a = int(exp(x/p)+0.5);
        if (qpow(a,p) == n) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        cout << (isPow(n) ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
    }
}
```

проходит за ту же миллисекунду, что и первое... :)

Comment: `qpow` красивый.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Тогда нужен перебор по корням... Но я и писал, что неоптимально, но все равно e-olymp проходит.

Comment: Да, проходит. Да я вроде нашёл как поправить оригинальный код ТС. Там цикл по степеням корней. А их всего 28 (или 10 десять если брать только простые). Позже добавлю в свой ответ. Получается решение за константу.

Comment: Эта миллисекунда уходит на загрузку программы и чтение данных.